# Why does a raster with resolution 5x5m not create a grid with these dimensions?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, spatial-analyst

I created a 5m x 5m raster using ArcGIS 10.0 Spatial Analyst from a point file. As can be seen in the screenshots of the image and the table, the resulting grid has a higher resoluation than is actually stated. Can anyone explain why this is?

Here is the image of the points and raster: I expected the raster grid to be the same size as the distance between the points...ie 5m!

[image: Raster]

and here is the table

[image]

Comment: What were your precise steps - tools and parameters - to create the raster and the points?

Comment: Please explain the steps you used to create the raster.

Comment: IDW Tool from Spatial Analyst > Interpolation /( Output size 5 / Power 2 / Search Radius = Variable 12 - Maximal Distance 10 / (no barriers)

Comment: Would you be able to revise your Question by editing those details into it and how you created the points too?

Comment: This is not some symbology issue is it? If your image is truly  a cell size of 5,5 then may be it is some weird rendering problem. Start a new instance of arcmap and load the resulting raster into that, does it look as expected?

Comment: Could this be the result of display rendering?  e.g. Properties | Display | Resample during display using: [bilinear interpolation]

Comment: Based on the images shown above the distance between the points is not 5m but more like 50m. Also, as mentioned, please provide the exact steps and parameters of the interpolation process.

Comment: How can you tell the difference between the points without knowing the scale? I measured the distance between the points in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Please refer to [@Aaron's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89431/why-does-a-raster-with-resolution-5x5m-not-create-a-grid-with-these-dimensions#comment124459_89431).* The pixel dimensions of your created raster layer is correct (5x5m). However, the *source type* of your data is set to **continuous** - which is also correct (This is done automatically by the IDW tool).
 *(Learn more about continuous vs. discrete data types in the [ArcGIS help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q8000000n8000000).)*

[image: ArcGIS continuous data type screenshot.]

However, in order to display a *continuous data type raster layer*, ArcGIS uses a **resample technique** for a more smooth display by default. It is probably set to *"Bilinear interpolation"*. You can change the used resample method at ***Layer Properties -> Display -> Resample during display using...***

[image: ArcGIS raster resampling techniques screenshot]

Set it to ***Nearest Neighbor*** and the display of your data will match the 5x5m grid. *(Note that this setting affects the **display** of your data only; internally you will have a 5x5m grid with any settings, so there may be no need to change this if you are fine with the way the data is displayed, knowing that you have a 5x5m grid underneath.)*

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for clearing this up for me!